# Xamarin Forms Color

Tags: colors, xamarin.forms

I want to save a color chosen by user(it's a Xamarin.Forms.Color) in my local database, so I saved it as string using ToString method, the saved color is in this syntax: [Color: A=1, R=1, G=0.400000005960464, B=1, Hue=0.833333313465118, Saturation=1, Luminosity=0.699999988079071]
I want to retrieve it from the data base but I have to convert it back to Xamarin.Forms.Color (it has method like Color.FromHex or Color.FromHlsa or Color.FromRgb...)

Can anyone tell my the best way to convert it back?

Thanks

Comment: How do you get Color from user? Is it a list of constants, or from rgb , or from hex?

Comment: it's a list of xamarin forms colors

Answer (score 0):

You can store the RGB values in your local database and then convert those integers back with `Color.FromRBG(n,n,n);` or you can store a string and do it with `Color.FromHex("#"+ localDBProperty);` Here is a reference link:

https://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/Xamarin.Forms.Color.FromHex/p/System.String/

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it's a bit long to retrieve the values (double) then convert it to hex

Answer (score 0):

`Xamarin.Forms` `Color`s can be created either from ARGB, or from AHSL. The conversion from one mode to the other is made automatically, so you never have to save both format in your DB (you're storing ARGBHSL).

now, there are plenty of ways to create the color from a subset of those values:

```cs
public Color(double r, double g, double b, double a);
public static Color FromHex(string hex); //one of the following: #rgb, #argb, #rrggbb, #aarrggbb, the leading # is optional
public static Color FromUint(uint argb);
public static Color FromRgba(int r, int g, int b, int a);
public static Color FromRgb(int r, int g, int b);
public static Color FromRgba(double r, double g, double b, double a);
public static Color FromRgb(double r, double g, double b);
public static Color FromHsla(double h, double s, double l, double a = 1d);
```

I'm quite sure you'll find either a constructor or a factory method in those that fits your needs.

Comment: thanks for your answer I'll try to save the RGBA color in four different variables and get it back from the database.